# Unwanted text in output of Artisan Command in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

I am getting an unwanted string in the output of each command I run. Even when I run the unit test or call API, it returns 'ticket' appended output.

Here is the image:

[image]

I am using PhpStorm in Ubuntu, please tell me if anyone knows its reason.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget some print in your code?

Comment: @TheWildHealer yes, I am sure, I have tried my best to find out any string matching 'ticket' but I could not find anything.

Comment: @AliKhalil did you try extending search scope for "ticket" even to "vendors" folder? Or when you execute a blank php file out of the project, does it happen too? This is for sure forgotten print somewhere, you only have to find it. Try reinstalling laravel/artisan.

Comment: @TheWildHealer you were right, it was in my routes file. it was before the <?php tag, maybe due to this PhpStorm could not find it out. it took too much to find this. Thanks